# In the Julia language, how are function compilations reused?

Tags: julia

I'm toying around with Julia, and I have run into a question about the compiler/JIT compilation scheme that Julia uses.  If I write a function such as

```
function f(x) 
  return mapreduce(*,+,x,x)
end
```

Then since this function works on abstract arrays, its shape can't be known until it's used, so it can't be compiled.  Then if use this in a function, `g`, whose inputs are arrays of arrays of floats like so:

```
function g(y) 
  return mapreduce(f,+,y)
end
```

Or alternatively

```
function g2(y) 
  res = 0 
  for x in y 
    res = res + f(x)
  end
  return res 
end
```

Then, when we use `g`, say `g([[1,2],[3,4]])`, eventually `f` will be called.  Say it's called on `[1,2]` first.  Then it's compiled, and evaluated.  As far as I can tell, since `f([3,4])` is on the exact same type as `f([1,2])`, `f` will be reused (since the inputs are both 2 dimensional arrays of numbers).  However, when I type `@code_llvm(f([1,2]))` and `@code_llvm(f([3,4]))` I see that the names of the functions are different (they do have a common prefix, something like `julia_f_` and then its followed by a number).  Also, if I call `@code_llvm(f([1,2]))` again, I get yet another name.

Does Julia indeed allow `g` to reuse the compiled version of `f` for each application?  Does this depend on the length of the arrays involved; i.e. in `g([w1,...,wn])` does each `wi` have to have the same length for `f` to be reused?

Comment: I _think_ this is just a printing issue (or perhaps a side effect of looking at the implementation via `@code_llvm`).  Those internal function names don't accurately reflect what Julia does in practice.

Comment: This doesn't completely answer the question, but it may be of some help: https://julialang.org/blog/2020/08/invalidations/#method_invalidation_what_is_it_and_when_does_it_happen

Answer (score 5):

I don't know much about Julia internals, but perhaps this provides some evidence that `f` is only compiled once:

```
function f(x) 
    mapreduce(*, +, x, x)
end

function g(y) 
    mapreduce(f, +, y)
end
```

```
julia> @time g([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
  0.099061 seconds (322.72 k allocations: 19.687 MiB, 99.94% compilation time)
30

julia> @time g([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
  0.000021 seconds (11 allocations: 672 bytes)
30
```

The first time `g` is run, 99.94% of the time is spent on compilation. The second time `g` is run, 0% of the time is spent on compilation. Note that you need Julia v1.6+ if you want to get the compilation time from the `@time` macro.